# Как распарсить строку из json

Tags: c, json

Как распарсить строку в си с помощью библиотеки jansson

```
{
    "status": true,
    "data": [ 1,3,-5,6,5 ]
}
```

Comment: Очевидно прочитать документацию к библиотеке, если она есть. В противном случае читать код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как Вы спрашиваете лишь о том, как провести разбор данных, то я ничего не буду писать об установке самой библиотеки.
Допустим, Вам надо проинициализировать подобную структуру:

```
struct MyData {

    int status;
    int* data;
    size_t dataItemsCount; // Количество элементов в массиве data
};
```

Сделать это можно следующим образом:

```
//Ваши исходные данные
const char* inputString = "{ \
    \"status\": false, \
    \"data\": [ 1,3,-5,6,5 ] \
}";

//Объект, в котором будут храниться все разобранные данные
struct MyData myData;

//Указатель на коренной элемент Вашего JSON
json_t *root;
//Указатель на объект, содержащий информацию об ошибке разбора JSON
json_error_t error;

//Подготовить Ваши данные для разбора
root = json_loads( inputString, 0, &error );
//Если полученные данные изначально были некорректными, то оповестить об этом пользователя
if ( !root ) {

    fprintf( stderr, "Ошибка в строке номер %d: %s\n", error.line, error.text );
    return 1;
}

//Обработать значение поля "status"
json_t* status = json_object_get(root, "status");
myData.status = status->type == JSON_TRUE;

//Обработать значение поля "data"
json_t* data = json_object_get(root, "data");
size_t i;
json_t *arrayElement;
myData.dataItemsCount = json_array_size(data);
myData.data = malloc(myData.dataItemsCount * sizeof(int));
//Так как "data" - это массив, то необходимо пройтись по всем его элементам
json_array_foreach(data, i, arrayElement){

    myData.data[i] = json_number_value(arrayElement);
}

//Продемонстрировать полученные данные
printf("status: %d\n", myData.status);
printf("data: ");
for (i = 0; i < myData.dataItemsCount; i++) {

    printf("%d ", myData.data[i]);
}
printf("\n");

//Освободить использованные ресурсы
json_decref(root);
free(myData.data);
```

Comment: А что вернет `json_number_value()` в этой библиотеке, если вместо очередного числа в массиве окажется, допустим, строка (или объект)? Возможно перед ее вызовом надо исследовать тип `arrayElement` вызвав еще какую-то функцию этой либы?

Comment: @avp В моём примере я обращался к полю type структуры json_t, в нём хранится тип переменной (JSON_TRUE, JSON_INTEGER и т.п.), на основании этого можете проверять, с помощью какой функции нужно обрабатывать значение. Но автору вопросу, насколько я понял, этого не требовалось.