# Как распарсить строку json в Qt

Tags: c++, qt

Помогите распарсить строку (`QString`) в `Qt`:

```
{
    "status": true,                             
    "data": [ 12,34,54 ]                     
}
```

Comment: Думаю, что  же это такое знакомое, а точно, уже был такой [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/656731), но по си :)

Answer (score 3):

Что в вашем понимании "распарсить"? Распарсить во что? Что должно быть на выходе?

Если хотите получить значения, проще всего использовать класс [`QJsonDocument`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsondocument.html):

```
QString jsonStr = "{ \"status\": true, \"data\": [ 12,34,54 ] }";
QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromJson(jsonStr.toUtf8());
QJsonObject jsonObj = jsonDoc.object();
for (const QString& eachKey : jsonObj.keys())
{
    qDebug() << eachKey << "=" << jsonObj.value(eachKey).toString();
}
```